# How to sum hours using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, sum

Hi I need to add hours in delphi, I have several hours data expressed in this manner 9:18:02, 8:15:19, 9:22:13 and I need to know the total of those hours, for example these three data would total of 26:55:34. The idea is to know the toal number of hours spent by a user. Thanks for help.

Comment: recalculate to seconds and then add?

Comment: this could be an option, but how I convert the hours to seconds?

Comment: Multiply hours by 60 to get minutes. Multiply minutes by 60 to get seconds.

Comment: I have tried using this code:

var
totaltime:TTime;
hHours   :TTime;
....
hHours:=StrToTime("Hours from BD");
totaltime:=totaltime+hHours;
....

but does not perform the sum correctly by the 24-hour limit

Answer (score 2):

If you want [whole](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.HoursBetween) hours:

```
var 
  totalHours: Integer;
...
totalHours := HoursBetween(0,StrToTime(s1) + StrToTime(s2) + StrToTime(s3));
```

If you want [fractional](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.HourSpan) hours:

```
var
  fracHours: Double;
...
fracHours := HourSpan(0,StrToTime(s1) + StrToTime(s2) + StrToTime(s3));
```

where s1,s2,s3 are your time values represented as strings.

Note, when working with date,time values, check out what the RTL has to offer: [Date and Time Support](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Date_and_Time_Support).

---

As mentioned in a comment by mg30rg, there are overloaded versions of [StrToTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToTime) and [TryStrToTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToTime) that handles specific locale conversions of a time string plus eliminates the effect of possible threads changing the application conversion settings. Read what the docs say about [TFormatSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.Create) in the links above.

Real code should also handle possible conversion errors.

Comment: That is a Locale dependent solution and does not necessairly work in every environment. If you want that to work in every Locale you have to create a `TFormatSettings` instance and set the `LongTimeFormat` and `TimeSeparator` fields, then call `StrToTime(const Time: string; const FormatSettings: TFormatSettings): TDateTime` with your `TFormatSettings` instance as second parameter.

Comment: @mg30rg, yes that is correct and to make it safer one should use [TryStrToTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToTime).

Comment: StrToTime is a very unsafe function to use.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt Not if you use it wisely.

Comment: @Jens StrToTime and TryStrToTime are as safe as each other

Answer (score 2):

Here's a back to basics guide on how you might implement this yourself:

1. Split the strings on `:` to get three strings, hours, minutes, seconds.
2. Use `StrToInt` to convert these three values to integers.
3. Use the fact that there are 60 seconds in a minute and 60 minutes in an hour to convert the time durations to seconds.
4. Sum the values.
5. Divide seconds by 60. The remainder is the final number of seconds, the result of the division is the total number of minutes. Use `div` and `mod`.
6. Divide the total minutes calculated in the previous step by 60. The remainder is the number of minutes, the result of the division is the number of hours.
7. Use `Format` to reconstitute a string containing the final answer.

In other words, you convert the time spans to seconds, add them up, and then convert back to hours, minutes and seconds. The arithmetic involved here is pretty basic.

---

However, the [`System.TimeSpan`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TimeSpan) unit already has what you need.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.TimeSpan;

var
  Total: TTimeSpan;

begin
  Total := TTimeSpan.Parse('9:18:02') + TTimeSpan.Parse('8:15:19') +
    TTimeSpan.Parse('9:22:13');
  Writeln(Format('%d:%.2d:%.2d', [Total.Days * 24 + Total.Hours, Total.Minutes,
    Total.Seconds]));
end.
```

**Output:**

```
26:55:34
```

It is a little messy I suppose in that you need to convert the days to hours, but that should not be too much of a hardship.

Comment: Thats an ugly hack. You should use the functions of the RTL of Delphi

Comment: @JensBorrisholt Not really ugly. Simple to implement and certainly worth knowing how to. Asker possibly has never done so before so useful to understand the concept. And contrary to what your answer states, the RTL already has all that is needed, namely `TTimeSpan`. Perhaps you are using an old version of Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Delphi wick can give you the desired result.

I have written you a small class to do the tick for you :

```
unit HourU;

interface

{$M+}
uses
  SysUtils;

const
  TimeSeparatorUsed: Char = ':';

Type
  THour = record
  private
    FHours: Word;
    FMinutes: Word;
    FSeconds: Word;
  public
    constructor Create(aDateTime: TDateTime);
    function ToString: String;
    function ToLongString: String;
    property Hours: Word read FHours;
    property Minutes: Word read FMinutes;
    property Seconds: Word read FSeconds;
  end;

  THourCalculator = class
  private
    FTotalHours: Double;
    FFormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
    function GetTotalHours: THour;
  public
    constructor Create;
    function Add(const Value: Double): THourCalculator; overload;
    function Add(const Value: String): THourCalculator; overload;
    property TotalHours: THour read GetTotalHours;
  end;

implementation

{ THourCalculator }

constructor THourCalculator.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FTotalHours := 0;
  FFormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create;
  FFormatSettings.TimeSeparator := TimeSeparatorUsed;
end;

function THourCalculator.GetTotalHours: THour;
begin
  Result := THour.Create(FTotalHours);
end;

function THourCalculator.Add(const Value: String): THourCalculator;
var
  Time: TDateTime;
begin
  if TryStrToTime(Value, Time, FFormatSettings) then
    Add(Time);
  Result := Self;
end;

function THourCalculator.Add(const Value: Double): THourCalculator;
begin
  FTotalHours := FTotalHours + Value;
  Result := Self;
end;

{ THour }

constructor THour.Create(aDateTime: TDateTime);
var
  Value: TDateTime;
  MSec: Word;
begin
  Value := aDateTime - Trunc(aDateTime);
  DecodeTime(Value, FHours, FMinutes, FSeconds, MSec);
  inc(FHours, Trunc(aDateTime) * HoursPerDay);
end;

function THour.ToLongString: String;
begin
  Result := Format('%d Hours, %d Minutes and %d Seconds', [FHours, FMinutes, FSeconds]);
end;

function THour.ToString: String;
begin
  Result := Format('%d%1:s%d%1:s%d', [FHours, TimeSeparatorUsed, FMinutes, FSeconds]);
end;

end.
```

First save the unit, and add it to uses.

Then here's an example of how to use it :

```
uses
  HourU;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HourCalculator: THourCalculator;
  Hour: THour;
begin
  HourCalculator := THourCalculator.Create;
  Hour := HourCalculator.Add('9:18:02').Add('8:15:19').Add('9:22:13').TotalHours;
  ShowMessage(Hour.ToString);
  ShowMessage(Hour.ToLongString);
  FreeAndNil(HourCalculator);
end;
```

Comment: You should check for and correct the spelling mistakes

Comment: Ignoring a failure of TryStrToTime seems unwise

Comment: Yuo are right David. The code should some how handle a failure of TryStrToTime

Comment: I have to say, I find this code to be heavily over engineered.  You need to instantiate a class to add two time values together? That feels all wrong. What's wrong with operator overloading on the record? And `THour` is a rather weak name for something with properties named `Hour`, `Minutes` and `Seconds`. I know English isn't your first language, but there it is. And having commented to my answer that RTL functionality should be used instead of re-inventing the wheel, you then declare that the RTL has no useful functionality. And yet it does: `TTimeSpan`.

Comment: What a funny question this has turned out to be. From ugly hack to code doing the tick for you and nothing in Delphi that can help yuo and code should some how handle a failure of TryStrToTime :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version using TTimeSpan

```
uses
  Timespan;

type
  TTimeSpanHelper = record helper for TTimeSpan
  private
    function TotalHours: Integer;
  public
    function sAdd(const Value: String): TTimeSpan;
    function ToString: String;
    function ToLongString: String;
  end;


{ TTimeSpanHelper }

function TTimeSpanHelper.sAdd(const Value: String): TTimeSpan;
begin
  Result := Add(TTimeSpan.Parse(Value));
end;

function TTimeSpanHelper.ToLongString: String;
begin
  Result := Format('%d:%d:%d', [TotalHours, Minutes, Seconds]);
end;

function TTimeSpanHelper.ToString: String;
begin
  Result := Format('%d Hours, %d Minutes and %d Seconds', [TotalHours, Minutes, Seconds]);
end;

function TTimeSpanHelper.TotalHours: Integer;
begin
  Result := Days * HoursPerDay + Hours;
end;


procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HourCalculation: TTimeSpan;
begin
  HourCalculation := TTimeSpan.Parse('9:18:02').sAdd('8:15:19').sAdd('9:22:13');
  ShowMessage(HourCalculation.ToString);
  ShowMessage(HourCalculation.ToLongString);
end;
```